# Access value from JSON object based on if ID is in a nested object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object nested inside a param for parent json objects. I'm trying to access a property of the parent based on if an ID exists in the ID field of the child objects.

The JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
    id: 1,
    map: "test",
    parameter_definitions: [{ID: 1, parameterUnits: "%"},{ID: 2, parameterUnits: "%"}],
},
{
    id: 2,
        map: "test2",
    parameter_definitions: [{ID: 3, parameterUnits: "%"},{ID: 4, parameterUnits: "%"}],
}
```

The value I need to return is the map of the right json object based on if my given value is one of the IDs in the parameter_definitions object. I can't seem to wrap my head around what this consists of.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function "getMapElementById" will help you:

```js
  let maps = [{
                 id: 1,
                 map: "test",
                 parameter_definitions: [{ID: 1, parameterUnits: "%"},{ID: 2, parameterUnits: "%"}],
                },
                {
                  id: 2,
                  map: "test2",
                  parameter_definitions: [{ID: 3, parameterUnits: "%"},{ID: 4, parameterUnits: "%"}],
                 }]


    function getMapElementById( maps, requiredId ) {

          for(let i=0;i<maps.length;i++){
              for(let j=0;j<maps[i].parameter_definitions.length;j++){
                  if( maps[i].parameter_definitions[j].ID == requiredId ) {
                     return maps[i];
                  }
              }
          }

    }

    let mapResult = getMapElementById(maps, 3);
    console.log(mapResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your question is not very clear. Is this what you are looking for?

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const myData = [{ id: 1, map: 'test', parameter_definitions: [{ ID: 1, parameterUnits: '%' }, { ID: 2, parameterUnits: '%' }] }, { id: 2, map: 'test2', parameter_definitions: [{ ID: 3, parameterUnits: '%' }, { ID: 4, parameterUnits: '%' }] }];

const getRootElement = (data, id) => objectScan(['[*].parameter_definitions[*].ID'], {
  abort: true,
  filterFn: ({ value, parents, context }) => {
    if (value === id) {
      context.push(...parents);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data, [])[2];

console.log(getRootElement(myData, 5));
// => undefined

console.log(getRootElement(myData, 3));
// => { id: 2, map: 'test2', parameter_definitions: [ { ID: 3, parameterUnits: '%' }, { ID: 4, parameterUnits: '%' } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether multiple parent objects can have children object with the same id, but either way, you could use a combination of filter and find:

```
let objects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        map: "test",
        parameter_definitions: [{ ID: 1, parameterUnits: "%" }, { ID: 2, parameterUnits: "%" }],
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        map: "test2",
        parameter_definitions: [{ ID: 3, parameterUnits: "%" }, { ID: 4, parameterUnits: "%" }],
    }
];

let filteredObjects = objects.filter(object => object.parameter_definitions.find(param => param.ID === 2));
if (filteredObjects.length > 0) {
  // If you know there will only be one parent object per child object ID, just return the first from the array
  console.log(filteredObjects[0].map);

  // If several parent objects can have the same child object ID, you can use the map function to get the map property of all the parent objects
  console.log(filteredObjects.map(object => object.map));
}
```